# Invoke-WMIMethod convert to Invoke-CimMethod with ciminstance as Argument error

Tags: powershell, wmi, sccm

So, trying to trigger a software update in SCCM with Invoke-CimMethod instead of Invoke-WMIMethod.

WMIMethod Works:

```
$UpdateID = 'Site_1EED8E47-D4D8-4823-883C-4FFE753FA233/SUM_0af47e05-17cb-4756-8610-09ce486df1ba'
$FeatureUpdate = Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\CCM\ClientSDK -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdate -Filter "UpdateID like '$UpdateID'"
Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace Root\ccm\clientSDK -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager -Name InstallUpdates -ArgumentList $FeatureUpdate
```

Note that $FeatureUpdate is a instance of an update:

```
$FeatureUpdate.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ManagementObject                         System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
```

Now with Invoke-CimMethod:

```
$Instance=Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\CCM\ClientSDK -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdate -Filter "UpdateID like '$UpdateID'"
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace Root\ccm\clientSDK -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager -MethodeName InstallUpdates -Arguments @{CCMUpdates = $Instance}

Invoke-CimMethod : Type mismatch for parameter "CCMUpdates"
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager -Namespace Roo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (Root\CCM\Client...eUpdatesManager:String) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand
```

Note the Instance:

```
$instance.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     CimInstance                              System.Object
```

Am I missing something on triggering the install with the arguments?  Not sure if this helps..

```
(((Get-CimClass -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager).CimClassMethods)|where {$_.name
 -like 'InstallUpdates'}).parameters

Name             CimType Qualifiers                 ReferenceClassName
----             ------- ----------                 ------------------
CCMUpdates InstanceArray {EmbeddedInstance, ID, in}


(((Get-CimClass -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -Class CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager).CimClassMethods)|where {$_.name
 -like 'InstallUpdates'}).parameters.Qualifiers

Name             Value              CimType                       Flags
----             -----              -------                       -----
EmbeddedInstance CCM_SoftwareUpdate  String  EnableOverride, ToSubclass
ID               0                   SInt32 DisableOverride, ToSubclass
in               True               Boolean DisableOverride, ToSubclass
```

Comment: I guess it has to be type ccm_softwareupdate[]? I don't have that class or namespace.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/clients/sdk/installupdates-method-in-class-ccm_softwareupdatesmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after letting it sit for the day. Found some posts to lead me in the right direction.

Final final:

```
$UpdateID = 'Site_1EED8E47-D4D8-4823-883C-4FFE753FA233/SUM_0af47e05-17cb-4756-8610-09ce486df1ba'
$Instance = @(Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -ClassName CCM_SoftwareUpdate -Filter "UpdateID like '$UpdateID'")
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -ClassName CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager -MethodName InstallUpdates -Arguments @{CCMUpdates = [ciminstance[]]$Instance}
```

Returns, and updates install:

```
ReturnValue PSComputerName
----------- --------------
          0
```