# Do the newer CIM cmdlets follow a different protocol for remote systems?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I've been trying to install some remote updates that are in error state (well any updates in general), but continue to get and error of:

```
No instance found with given property values.
```

. . that's it. That's the only error that is displayed with no further info given. Looking at the the documents for [`Invoke-CimMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/invoke-cimmethod?view=powershell-7.2), it show's that it expects an argument of: `[[-Arguments] <IDictionary>]`, which is fine, but i'm just not understanding what I may be doing wrong.

Currently I am grabbing the available updates on the remote system. Outputting to `Out-GridView` for a selection, and using `Invoke-CimMethod` to try and invoke the installation:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace $nameSpace `
                 -ClassName "CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager" `
                 -CimSession $CIMSession `
                 -Arguments @{ 
                    CCMUpdates = [ciminstance[]]$_ 
                 } -MethodName "InstallUpdates" -ErrorAction Stop
```

So far, from other posts like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/goe9o8/error_when_working_with_wmi_and_software_center/), the argument value has to be of CIMInstance; which they are when running `.GetType().FullName` on the current instance from the pipeline: `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance`. . .but, according to that same post with the same error, the issue was that the instances had to not have been saved to a variable? Only way that would make sense is that it needs to not be a de-serialized instance? Either way, I gave their suggestion a try but, still got the same error.

**Question**: Is there something that I am doing wrong with passing the arguments to the command for it to continue to give me that error?

So here is the rest of the code in hopes that someone smarter than me can help me understand what is the cause here:

```
Function Install-SCUpdates {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$Force
    )
    Begin
    {
        $nameSpace = "root\ccm\clientSDK"
        $className = "CCM_SoftwareUpdate"

        $EvaluationState = @{
            0  = 'None'
            1  = 'Available'
            2  = 'Submitted'
            3  = 'Detecting'
            4  = 'PreDownload'
            5  = 'Downloading'
            6  = 'WaitInstall'
            7  = 'Installing'
            8  = 'PendingSoftReboot'
            9  = 'PendingHardReboot'
            10 = 'WaitReboot'
            11 = 'Verifying'
            12 = 'InstallComplete'
            13 = 'Error'
            14 = 'WaitServiceWindow'
            15 = 'WaitUserLogon'
            16 = 'WaitUserLogoff'
            17 = 'WaitJobUserLogon'
            18 = 'WaitUserReconnect'
            19 = 'PendingUserLogoff'
            20 = 'PendingUpdate'
            21 = 'WaitingRetry'
            22 = 'WaitPresModeOff'
            23 = 'WaitForOrchestration'
        }
    }
    Process
    {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
        {
            Try {
                $CIMSession   = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop
                $updatesFound = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $nameSpace -ClassName $className -CimSession $CIMSession
                    if ($updatesFound) {
                        if ($Force) {
                            $null = Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName "InstallUpdates" -Namespace $nameSpace -ClassName "CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager" -Arguments @{CCMUpdates = [ciminstance[]]$updatesFound} -CimSession $CIMSession
                            $updatesFound | Select-Object -Property ArticleID, 
                                @{
                                    Name='Status';
                                    Expression = {
                                        $Code = [int]$_.EvaluationState.ToString().Trim()
                                        $EvaluationState.$code
                                    }
                                }, Name
                        }
                        else {
                            $selectedSoftware = $updatesFound | Select-Object -Property ArticleID, 
                                @{
                                    Name='Status';
                                    Expression = {
                                        $Code = [int]$_.EvaluationState.ToString().Trim()
                                        $EvaluationState.$code
                                    }
                                }, Name,Description | Out-GridView -Title $Computer -PassThru
                                if ($selectedSoftware) {
                                    $selectedSoftware = $updatesFound.Where{
                                        $_.Name -in $selectedSoftware.Name
                                    }
                                    $selectedSoftware  | ForEach-Object -Process `
                                    {
                                        #$_.GetType().FullName
                                        #$cimInstance = [ciminstance[]](Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM $className WHERE updateID='$($_.UpdateID)'" -Namespace $nameSpace -CimSession $CIMSession)
                                        #$cimInstance | gm 
                                        #Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName "InstallUpdates" -Namespace $nameSpace -ClassName "CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager" -Arguments @{CCMUpdates = $cimInstance } -CimSession $CIMSession
                                        #Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $_ -MethodName InstallUpdates -CimSession $CIMSession
                                        $updateID = $_.UpdateID
                                        Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace $nameSpace `
                                                         -ClassName "CCM_SoftwareUpdatesManager" `
                                                         -CimSession $CIMSession `
                                                         -Arguments @{ 
                                                            CCMUpdates = [ciminstance[]]$_ 
                                                        } -MethodName "InstallUpdates" -ErrorAction Stop
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                    $selectedSoftware | Select-Object -Property "ArticleID", 
                                        @{
                                            Name='Status';
                                            Expression = {
                                                $Code = [int]$_.EvaluationState.ToString().Trim()
                                                $EvaluationState.$code
                                            }
                                        }, "Name"
                                }
                                else {
                                    Write-Host -Object "No software selected to install.`n"
                                    Continue
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Write-Host -Object "No updates Found!:)"
                    }
            }
            Catch {
                Write-Host -Object $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
            }
            Finally {
                if (Get-CimSession) {
                    Get-CimSession | Remove-CimSession
                }
            }
        }
    }
    End { }
}
```

---

*There really shouldn't be no expected output other than that of the command actually running successfully*.

Comment: Coming with a hard one today huh :) what does change between your code and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61735332/invoke-wmimethod-convert-to-invoke-cimmethod-with-ciminstance-as-argument-error) ? Are you able to run a single `Invoke-CimMethod` with hard-coded values and does this only happen on your function?

Comment: @Santi, didn't want to post without some googling first! Lol honestly, it seems all the same, seeing as I seen the same post earlier as well. Only real difference is the invocation against a remote computer. I wasn't able to try it out locally, so will find a machine needing updates then see if anything changes. Just seems odd. Saw other threads people gave up on this, and reverted back to the older wmi cmdlets.

Comment: Hope you can find an answer to this, might be handy to have the code producing the error to the lowest added to your question to help others help you debug it.

Comment: Will add it in hopes I get some help! Lol thanks man:)

Comment: Have you seen the workaround that [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65823372/9898643) posted? Could that also work for you?